# Binary Protocols to/from .NET (C# syntax)

Tags: c#, .net, binary, protocols

I would like to hear how you would solve this sort of programming task!?
Each type (OPER = 1 type) corresponds to a specific information.

This is just one of about 10 specifications with same structure. A generic way to create those "converters" (protocol) is preferred.

[image: Protocol specification]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are reading/writing this, I would simply translate it at the `Stream` level, somthing like:

```
int b = source.ReadByte();
if (b < 0) throw new EndOfStreamException();
int operx = b & 15;
int oper = (b >> 4) & 15;            
b = source.ReadByte();
if (b < 0) throw new EndOfStreamException();
int prefix = b & 7;
int reg = (b >> 3) & 31;
b = source.ReadByte();
if (b < 0) throw new EndOfStreamException();
int period = b & 7;
int fas = (b >> 3) & 3;
int tar = (b >> 5) & 7;
```

If you are doing **lots** of it, you could wrap it up into something more elegant, perhaps using attributes to specify the offsets - but for 10? meh... not worth it. Writing a robust *generic* converter is **lots** of hard work.

Comment: Thank's. Bitwise Shift operators  is not really my school, perhaps until now? Though I think I see what this sample gives me. Would you like to give it a short description? 15, 31? I will say that this table is the biggest of about a dousin (with 1-20 options per bit-block)

Comment: @dingir 15 decimal is binary 1111, i.e. captures the right-most 4 bits. So looking (for example) at `(b >> 4) & 15`, this is actually "take the left half of the byte as an integer" - by shifting 4 bits and then taking 4 bits. Likewise, `(b >> 3) & 31` allows us to access "reg" - we discard the 3 bites that make up "prefix", and take 5 bits (decimal 31 is binary 11111)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to mask and shift the bits then you could use the BitVector32 structure.  Its CreateSection() method lets you split up to 4 bytes into groups of bits, the indexer then lets you read and write the bit values.